# pygame_sdl2 error: not implented

Tags: python, pygame

I'm building a android app using pygame_sdl2, pygame, and pgs4a, and when I tried to run my app on my PC (as a Python File, not an android app), I got this error:

[image]

You can find my code [here](https://pastebin.com/fVYvw0W0).

Thanks for your time, OrionDark7

Comment: Sorry if the image isn't showing up. I'll put up another pastebin link if you aren't able to see it.

Comment: It means exactly what is says. Pygame_SDL2 does not implement every part of Pygame (yet), just most of it. This is one of the features that never got ported.

Comment: So, should I just wait until the next release comes out? Or is there something I can do about it.

Comment: The Pygame developers are currently implementing SDL2 into official Pygame. If Pygame_SDL2 does not meet your needs, then I would just wait until the official release.

Comment: Okay, I found an alternative for now though.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, as Remolten said, some parts of pygame have not been implented into pygame_sdl2. But here is an alternative:

First, don't load pygame_sdl2, just pygame, and then the surface will blit to the window.

From there, you can take a screenshot of the surface you are trying to blit,  and save it as an image.

Re-import pygame_sdl2, and load the image instead.

This is what I have tried and it worked, pygame_sdl2 can display images, but not some shapes.